# Converting a line of code to be compatible with storyboards in XCode 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue

For an IOS project I am using MWFeedParser to essentially create an RSS reader.
I am populating a tableview with the RSS feed and now want to create that segue using story board.

I can't seem to get it working. I'd normally would use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to push the detail view.

Help is much appreciated..

Thanks

This is what I'd normally do:

```
 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        // Show detail
        DetailTableViewController *detail = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        detail.item = (MWFeedItem *)[itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
        [detail release];

        // Deselect
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    }
```

I've wired up my views and the segue in Stroyboard. My identifier for the segue in question is: `ShowSelectedFeed`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new Master-Detail-Application and use it as a reference. It uses exactly that pattern.

If you have created the segue in the storyboard you want to use `prepareForSegue:sender:` to pass your data. Something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

That's directly from the Master-Detail-Application template. Adjust it to your needs